# subscriptions scope in Youtube Data API v.3

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

In my project user have to activate it by subscribing our channel, so I use the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube` scope. User sees it like I want to manage his YouTube account, but I want only to subscribe our channel.

Please add the subscriptions scope into Youtube Data API v.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the YouTube API works. It allows you to create an application that gives you access to a USERS YouTube account.

[Subscriptions: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert)using one of the following scopes

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl

Will allow the users to add subscriptions to any YouTube channel using your application.  If you want to limit it to your own channel then this is something you would have to do in code in your application.

> Please add the subscriptions scope into Youtube Data API v.3. Thanks!

Stack overflow is not google nor are we google support we do not have the power to add any scopes for you.  I suggest you submit a feature request directly with google [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803)